# Web story where the earth is encased in a heavenly glass/diamond

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a recent web story (not a comic but a sort of online novel) where the first astronauts attempt to leave the atmosphere but instead find that the earth is encased in a divine sort of jewel. After they crash into it, the jewel is broken and demons flood the earth. It's named after some sort of theory about heavenly bodies but I can't remember that either.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When you say "recent" do you mean this month, this year, or in the past 5 years?  How long was it?  (And have you read David Brin's [take on the theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crystal_Spheres)?)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. In terms of recent I think published between 2010 and 2020. In terms of length I'm unsure, but likely medium length for a web serial (500k words?) Haven't read David Brin's take, but it is curious to hear that "planets, but surrounded by crystals" is a genre.

Comment: I'm guessing the theory cited was Mysterium Cosmographicum.  Does that sound familiar?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysterium_Cosmographicum

Comment: @Laura: You should edit those clarifications into the question itself :)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but your description reminded me of a book I read a while back called Spin. It was very good Here's the [amazon link](https://www.amazon.com/Spin-1-Robert-Charles-Wilson/dp/1250237513/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1657821448&sr=8-1) if you're interested!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of [*Unsong*](https://unsongbook.com/) by Scott Alexander.  It was originally published as a web serial around 2017.

The [TVTropes work page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Unsong) describes it:

> In 1968, the crew of Apollo 8 crashes into the crystal sphere that surrounds Earth. The logic of the world as we know it falls apart, the Names of God become magical spells, and all of Judeo-Christian theology is suddenly true. The Messiah reads Peter Singer and founds a kingdom in Colorado, The Legions of Hell rise from a lake in Siberia and ally with Henry Kissinger against Soviet Russia, Silicon Valley giants research esoteric Jewish mysticism through brute-force algorithms, and the Unitarian Church leads a secret underground in opposition to the United Nations Subcommittee on the Names of God.

Comment: This is totally it! Thank you :)
Accepted

Answer (score 8):

David Brin's [The crystal Spheres](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12298550), first published in 1984.

> In a universe filled with habitable worlds, why have we had no contact with extra-terrestrial intelligence? "The Crystal Spheres" offers a fantastic explanation for the Great Silence. Instead of being late-comers -- might humanity have come upon the scene too early? This haunting tale was voted one of the "most beautiful of the eighties." Winner of the 1985 Hugo Award

After decades or centuries of finding other solar systems also enclosed in their own crystal Spheres which are unbreakable from the outside an exploration crew find an open solar system.

While there are no demons, the breaching of the sphere does cause an ongoing disaster on earth as the solar system is bombarded by the resulting fragments.

I am pretty sure this used to be available as a free online story, I have a PDF version of it on my Kindle, but [Brin's website](https://www.davidbrin.com/shortstories.html) shows only for purchase options today.

Comment: Two points: 1) OP has already said this isn't it (see comment) and 2) it's available at [*Lightspeed Magazine*](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-crystal-spheres/).

Comment: @DavidW totally missed the comment. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One other important point.  Despite the fact this is probably Brin at his most twee, I still have a fondness for the story.  You can't hate sentences like "In my time, there were four ways known to cheat Einstein, and two ways to flat-out fool him." :D

Comment: Worth saying here that it was first published in 1984.